# Jquery translate multiple times with button

Tags: jquery, css, button, transform, translate

How to make a button which triggers CSS translate multiple times?

```
<button>CLICK</button>

// CLICK
$(document).ready(function () {

$('button').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (button clicked once) {

        $('section').css({'-webkit-transform':'translateY( 100%) '});

    } else if (button clicked second time) {

        $('section').css({'-webkit-transform':'translateY( 200% )'});

    } else if (button clicked second time) {

        $('section').css({'-webkit-transform':'translateY( 300% )'});
    }        

    return false;
});
});
```

Or maybe there is other approach to make CSS translate? P.S I know I can replace .css with .addclass

Comment: Why don't you just take a `counter` variable and increase it to `+1` every time when you click a button!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
var count = 1;
$('button').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('section').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(' + (100 * count) + '%) '
    });
    count += 1;
});
```

- First time `button` is clicked `count` would be 1, so translateY would correspond to `100*1=100%`
- Second time `count` is incremented by 1, so translateY would be `100*2=200%`
- and so on...

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to make another button which translates in different direction? Something like next and previous buttons.

Comment: Yup, just do `count -= 1` and same logic in another button;

Comment: I figured it out after I wrote... But thank you so much  for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```js
// CLICK
var clickCount = 0;
$('button').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  clickCount -= 1;
  if ( clickCount >= -3 ) {
    var percentage = clickCount + '00%';
    $('section').css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(' + percentage + ') '
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<section>Abcd</section>
```

Comment: Would that not be `'-webkit-transform': 'translateY( '+clickcount+'00% )' ?

Comment: This may be what I want, but it translates down and I need to translate up

Comment: @user3609605 Then set it to translate a negative amount `'-webkit-transform': 'translateY(-' + percentage + ') '`  see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qsf0tcg8/

Comment: A massive thanks to you all! It worked like a charm.